# Livewire - updated Lifecycle Hook is not detecting unchecking of checkbox

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have some checkboxes:

```
@foreach ($inventoryItems as $item)
    <input type="checkbox" wire:model="parts" name="parts[]" 
        value="{{ $item->id }}">
@endforeach
```

I check if they get modified by

```
public function updatedParts()
{
    dump(1);
}
```

I expect to see the dump either when the checkbox gets checked or unchecked, but I see it when the checkbox gets checked only. Is there something wrong with my input or with my understand of what the updated lifecycle hook does? The documentation is very unclear at this point.

Comment: Do you have a public property named `parts`?

Comment: Yes, sure. The property is there

Comment: @JanBoehmer Is your public property either typehinted as `array` or, has a default value of `[]`? Livewire will handle checkboxes as boolean if not specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

in livewire inputs, you should not use the `name` property. `wire:model`, or `wire:defer.model` is enough. remove the `name` in your input

Comment: You can have a name attribute if you want, doesn't change anything. And there's already `wire:model` on it.

Comment: I can confirm. Removing the name attribute doesn't change anything. The issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($inventoryItems as $item)
                    <input type="checkbox" value="$item->id"
                               wire:model="parts.{{ $item->id }}">
                        {{ $item->name }}
                @endforeach
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).